# how to define function with just a optional parameter in python that takes input if not given a argument

Tags: python

```
def crt_std(name=input("Enter the student name: ")): 
    std_dt={
        'name' : name,
        'marks' : []
        }
    return std_dt

def crt_std(name=None): 
    if name=None
        name=input("Enter the student name: ")
    std_dt={
        'name' : name,
        'marks' : []
        }
    return std_dt
```

'''In both of the functions I tried to create a dictionary with a name & number. I wanted to use the functions as if I pass a argument in the name parameter it would work, and if I don't then it would ask me for a input. Ironically both of them failed miserably.

Again, **I dont want the function to ask for input name if I call it via function argument like crt_std(rockzxm). I want the function to ask for input if i leave it blank like crt_std().**'''

Comment: `if name is None` in the second function. First function is invalid.

Comment: First variant will never work because "input" is executed too early and only once. Second variant needs only a few syntax corrections but is basically the right approach.

Comment: I dont want the function to ask for input name if I call it via function argument like crt_std(rockzxm). I want the function to ask for input if i leave it blank like crt_std().

Comment: "if name is None" didn't work. @rda5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works but you forgot to add a colon and you only wrote one '=' instead of two.

This works:

```
def crt_std(name = None): 
    if name == None:
        name = input("Enter the student name: ")
    std_dt = {
        'name' : name,
        'marks' : []
        }
    return std_dt
```